# Netbeans está identificando como erros aguns arquivos do Laravel. Como resolver isso?

Tags: laravel-5, netbeans

Eu acabei de instalar uma versão do Laravel 5 e abri o projeto no Netbeans 8.1. Estou rodando com PHP7.

Como pode se ver na foto, existem vários erros em diferentes pastas. Inclusive a pasta do projeto aparece em VERMELHO.  Instalei o [Laravel 5 IDE Helper Generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), mas nada mudou.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse código está correto mesmo? Consegue postar ele por escrito para que seja possível reproduzi-lo?

Comment: Posso sim.  Depois eu faço um update na pergunta e ponho o código. Se vc quiser basta criar um novo projeto de laravel com composer e vc terá o código.

Comment: Poxa, agora que vi melhor. Isso é um código dentro do seu vendor. Pode ignorar sem medo :)

Comment: Qual o erro acontece com o routes.php ?

Comment: nao tem erro nehum.... a minha questao é pq netbeans esta reconnhecendo como erro e como eliminar esse comportamento do netbeans

Comment: Sim, mas o que quero saber é o que exatamente ele está reconhecendo como erro ?

Comment: Eu verifiquei a aba amarela e fui pesquisar o erro. Parace algo ligado com nodeJs. De fato estou usando win7 e nao tem node instalado. Nem sabia que era pre-requisito para rodar laravel, ou para netbeans reconhecer as suas pastas. VOu instalar e dou uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Achei a resposta. Vou postar em fotos para ficar bem explicado.

1. Verifique a mensagem de problema não resolvido e a cor vermelha do nome do projeto:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Click com o botão direito do mouse e escolher `"Resolver Problemas do Projeto"`:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Ele vai mostrar o problema do projeto e a sua descrição. Nesse caso, algo ligado ao npm. Verifique se o npm ou o nodejs estão instalado na sua máquina. Abra o console e digite `node -v` e depois `npm -v`. No exmplo nenhum dos dois foram encontrados:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Vá ao site do node e faça o download apropriado para sua versão do sistema operacional, que vai ser automaticamente identificado:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Deixe o instalador escolher o diretório default e simplesmente aceite as opções até o fim.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. Depois de instalado, o xdebug já estava funcionando, mas o netbeans ainda indentificava algum erro. O nome contunua vermelho.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
7. Repita os passos 2 e 3. O netbeans continua acusando erro.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
8. Mesmo com o node e o  npm instalado. Aperte o botão resolve.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
9. O console do netbeans vai se abrir e vai começar a fazer alguns downloads.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
10. Depois de demorar muito, e mesmo com alguns warnings e erros de versão instalada, o netbeans já não mostra o warning anterior e a cor do nome do projeto volta ao normal:
    [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

UPDATE:
Vou postar o log gerado durante o processo de update solicitado pelo Netbeans.

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "install"
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130

> node-sass@3.8.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\testLara\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at C:\xampp\htdocs\testLara\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node

> node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\testLara\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"C:\xampp\htdocs\testLara\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
bootstrap-sass@3.3.7 node_modules\bootstrap-sass

gulp@3.9.1 node_modules\gulp
├── interpret@1.0.1
├── pretty-hrtime@1.0.2
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── tildify@1.2.0 (os-homedir@1.0.1)
├── semver@4.3.6
├── v8flags@2.0.11 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, supports-color@2.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (sequencify@0.0.7, stream-consume@0.1.0, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.14 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, strip-bom@1.0.0, defaults@1.0.3, vinyl@0.4.6, through2@0.6.5, mkdirp@0.5.1, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
├── liftoff@2.3.0 (lodash.isplainobject@4.0.5, lodash.isstring@4.0.1, lodash.mapvalues@4.5.1, rechoir@0.6.2, extend@3.0.0, flagged-respawn@0.3.2, resolve@1.1.7, fined@1.0.1, findup-sync@0.4.2)
└── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.3, beeper@1.1.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, fancy-log@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, gulplog@1.0.0, lodash.template@3.6.2, through2@2.0.1, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.12)

laravel-elixir@5.0.0 node_modules\laravel-elixir
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2
├── path@0.11.14
├── underscore@1.8.3
├── underscore-deep-extend@0.0.5
├── insert-css@0.2.0
├── require-dir@0.3.0
├── partialify@3.1.6 (string-to-js@0.0.1, through@2.3.8)
├── run-sequence@1.2.2 (chalk@1.1.3)
├── glob@5.0.15 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, once@1.3.3, inflight@1.0.5, minimatch@3.0.2)
├── parse-filepath@0.5.0 (path-ends-with@0.2.3)
├── gulp-rev@5.1.0 (rev-hash@1.0.0, object-assign@2.1.1, sort-keys@1.1.2, rev-path@1.0.0, vinyl-file@1.3.0, through2@0.6.5)
├── vinyl-paths@1.0.0 (through2@0.6.5)
├── merge-stream@0.1.8 (through2@0.6.5)
├── gulp-concat@2.6.0 (concat-with-sourcemaps@1.0.4, through2@0.6.5)
├── vinyl-source-stream@1.1.0 (vinyl@0.4.6, through2@0.6.5)
├── vinyl-buffer@1.0.0 (through2@0.6.5, bl@0.9.5)
├── gulp-rev-replace@0.4.3 (through2@2.0.1)
├── gulp-sourcemaps@1.6.0 (graceful-fs@4.1.5, convert-source-map@1.3.0, strip-bom@2.0.0, vinyl@1.2.0, through2@2.0.1)
├── gulp-batch@1.0.5 (async-done@1.2.2, stream-array@1.1.2)
├── del@1.2.1 (is-path-cwd@1.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, each-async@1.1.1, is-path-in-cwd@1.0.0, globby@2.1.0, rimraf@2.5.4)
├── gulp-coffee@2.3.2 (merge@1.2.0, coffee-script@1.10.0, through2@0.6.5, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4)
├── gulp-if@1.2.5 (through2@0.6.5, gulp-match@0.2.1, ternary-stream@1.2.3)
├── gulp-load-plugins@1.2.4 (array-unique@0.2.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, gulplog@1.0.0, fancy-log@1.2.0, resolve@1.1.7, findup-sync@0.4.2, micromatch@2.3.11)
├── gulp-watch@4.3.9 (object-assign@4.1.0, path-is-absolute@1.0.0, vinyl@0.5.3, readable-stream@2.1.4, glob-parent@2.0.0, vinyl-file@1.3.0, chokidar@1.6.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
├── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, beeper@1.1.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.3, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, fancy-log@1.2.0, minimist@1.2.0, has-gulplog@0.1.0, vinyl@0.5.3, chalk@1.1.3, lodash.template@3.6.2, gulplog@1.0.0, through2@2.0.1, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.12)
├── gulp-uglify@1.5.4 (uglify-save-license@0.4.1, deap@1.0.0, isobject@2.1.0, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1, fancy-log@1.2.0, through2@2.0.1, uglify-js@2.6.4)
├── gulp-notify@2.2.0 (node.extend@1.1.5, lodash.template@3.6.2, through2@0.6.5, node-notifier@4.6.0)
├── browserify@11.2.0 (browser-resolve@1.11.2, tty-browserify@0.0.0, https-browserify@0.0.1, constants-browserify@0.0.1, path-browserify@0.0.0, punycode@1.4.1, builtins@0.0.7, string_decoder@0.10.31, isarray@0.0.1, os-browserify@0.1.2, inherits@2.0.1, htmlescape@1.1.1, commondir@0.0.1, stream-browserify@2.0.1, assert@1.3.0, shell-quote@0.0.1, defined@1.0.0, domain-browser@1.1.7, process@0.11.7, xtend@4.0.1, querystring-es3@0.2.1, timers-browserify@1.4.2, util@0.10.3, deps-sort@1.3.9, events@1.0.2, parents@1.0.1, vm-browserify@0.0.4, has@1.0.1, console-browserify@1.1.0, readable-stream@2.1.4, url@0.10.3, subarg@1.0.0, concat-stream@1.4.10, through2@1.1.1, duplexer2@0.0.2, shasum@1.0.2, buffer@3.6.0, stream-http@1.7.1, read-only-stream@1.1.1, glob@4.5.3, JSONStream@1.1.4, browserify-zlib@0.1.4, resolve@1.1.7, syntax-error@1.1.6, labeled-stream-splicer@1.0.2, browser-pack@5.0.1, insert-module-globals@6.6.3, crypto-browserify@3.11.0, module-deps@3.9.1)
├── watchify@3.7.0 (defined@1.0.0, xtend@4.0.1, through2@2.0.1, outpipe@1.1.1, chokidar@1.6.0, anymatch@1.3.0, browserify@13.1.0)
├── gulp-autoprefixer@2.3.1 (object-assign@2.1.1, through2@0.6.5, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4, postcss@4.1.16, autoprefixer-core@5.2.1)
├── gulp-cssnano@2.1.2 (object-assign@4.1.0, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1, cssnano@3.7.3)
├── gulp-shell@0.5.2 (async@1.5.2, through2@2.0.1, lodash@4.14.1)
├── browser-sync@2.14.0 (emitter-steward@1.0.0, server-destroy@1.0.1, dev-ip@1.0.1, qs@6.2.0, immutable@3.8.1, ua-parser-js@0.7.10, opn@3.0.3, browser-sync-client@2.4.2, http-proxy@1.13.3, portscanner@1.0.0, resp-modifier@6.0.2, serve-static@1.10.3, connect@3.4.1, eazy-logger@3.0.2, chokidar@1.5.1, micromatch@2.3.8, fs-extra@0.26.7, socket.io@1.4.6, serve-index@1.7.3, yargs@4.7.1, localtunnel@1.8.1, bs-recipes@1.2.2, rx@4.1.0, easy-extender@2.3.2, browser-sync-ui@0.6.0)
├── gulp-sass@2.3.2 (lodash.clonedeep@4.4.1, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1, through2@2.0.1, node-sass@3.8.0)
├── babel-preset-react@6.11.1 (babel-plugin-syntax-flow@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@6.9.0, babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx@6.8.0, babel-plugin-syntax-jsx@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@6.11.0)
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.9.0 (babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.11.5, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.11.4, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.9.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.9.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.11.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.8.0, babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.10.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.8.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.9.0, babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.11.4)
├── babelify@7.3.0 (object-assign@4.1.0, babel-core@6.11.4)
├── gulp-babel@6.1.2 (object-assign@4.1.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1, through2@2.0.1, babel-core@6.11.4)
└── gulp-less@3.1.0 (object-assign@4.1.0, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1, through2@2.0.1, less@2.7.1, accord@0.23.0)
Done.
```

Comment: bem estranho isso ai, não pode ser um problema no ambiente? vou baixar o Netbeans aqui e ver se reproduzo.